# Is it possible to look up a Stack Exchange user by their email address?

Tags: support, profile-page

Is it possible to look up a Stack Exchange user by their email address?

If so, how can I disable this feature for my account?

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible unless you're a diamond moderator or an employee, and they aren't allowed to use that feature for personal gain.

Comment: Oh... ummm, I'll just go ahead and cancel that ConstantContact campaign... `<totallyKidding data-reason='not actually cancelling' />`

Comment: by employee, u mean stack exchange employee?

Comment: @feynman Yes, Stack Exchange employees.

Comment: 'MD5 hash of one's email address' seems to b another possibility, but anybody know how to do it in particular?